# How can I create a profile and rotate it to create a mesh using Blender 2.72?

Tags: modeling

I am having trouble finding a way to rotate a shape to make a mesh.  I found Youtube examples using older versions of Blender but none for the one we are using in the class I teach.  We are building a Civil War scene. It includes Ft. Sumter and a Steamship plus various items including a cannon.  I've decided to show my students two ways to make a cannon, if I can.  Here attached are some images that show my approaches.  I can show them how to do the modeling using a UV Sphere, but I think it is important to show both methods.  There should be some kind of menu option that asks for a line that would act as a rotation axis.[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Randy, you should accept the best answer as correct, I noticed you don't do this and your questions have some good views. Pls do it for all your questions thanks:)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a ***Screw Modifier***. Being in *Object Mode* select your profile and enable the modifier.
[image]

You have now a bunch of extra options. Set the desired axis you want your profile to screw along. Set the *Angle* to 360 degrees to have the whole form (or 180 if you want to have a half of the form). You may also increase the number of the *Steps*, so if you apply the modifier later you'll have more geometry. Please see this documentation for more details: 
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Screw
[image]

You may notice the strange behaviour of the normals after applying the modifier. Recalculate them using a *Tool Shelf* button or use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> shortcut, while in *Edit Mode*.
[image]

---

UPDATE: Placing the origin point to make the Screw Modifier work properly (according to Randy's situation).

I started with placing the inner vertices of the profile perfectly on the one axis.
Then I gave the mesh the same rotation and the origin point the same location like on your printscreens.
[image]

1. I entered the *Edit Mode* and selected two vertices as pictured below. Then snapped the *cursor to selection* using shortcut: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->Cursor to Selected.
2. I entered the *Object Mode* and snapped the *origin point to 3D cursor* using *Tool Shelf* button (you may also use the shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>-->Origin to 3D cursor).
3. With the origin point set I enabled the *Screw Modifier*.
   [image]

Comment: Even better, as you can just edit the one profile if at any time you want to make some changes. +1

Comment: I didn't remember this modifier. Both answers are good, +1 to both :)

Comment: Ok, I got this but the axis was not in the right place so it rotated wrong for me.  Then when I tried to undo this modifier, it undid some of the vertices instead.  Now when I try to start over with a new set of lines, Blender is set to screw the new lines before I want it to happen.  Help!

Comment: Redid this three times.  The last time was the closest.  Still, the axis of rotation varied from ideal.  How do I position the 3D cursor more accurately so as to make the axis of rotation where I want it to be?

Comment: @Randy, I've updated the answer. Please check it out.

Comment: Good edit! You can leave an edge there along the axis to snap your vertices on when modifying the rotated object. Delete it when finished.

Answer (score 13):

What you are looking for is the *Spin* tool. Set the *3D Cursor* to the position you want to spin around (generally the origin) and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. You will notice a bunch of options come up:

[image: Spin Tool Options]

This is located in the left menu, opened by pressing <kbd>T</kbd>.

[image: Spin Tool GIF]

Also you will need to remove doubles by selecting all vertices, and pressing <kbd>W</kbd> *> Remove Doubles*

For detailed information on all of the capabilities, go to [**the official documentation page**](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/spin.html).

Comment: don't forget to remove doubles when using spin tool. Center (xSteps) and 360° vertices are dupicates.

Comment: How are you doing that quick mode select thing in the gif? Is it an addon?

Comment: @Gwenn It is an official addon bundled with blender called Pie Menus, quite handy