# How to spin vertex

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode, screw-modifier

Today I tried to make some ugly models. My choice fell on [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bj5Lvb_T81Y).
At 5:10 the author spins the vertex. But in my case I got this

[image: screenshot of model]]([![enter image description here]

I tried to transform this vertex to mesh (don't ask me why, just i'm newbie) but it doesn't help.
All is fine if using *Screw* modifier but why I can't  produce moreover the same result with the Spin tool. It looks so mystically:

[image: screenshot 2 of the mesh]

Here is my blender file

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_-tV3odolwlSVVWeXpGOGVZd0k

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! I think it's just a matter of setting the right parameter for the tool in the Tool Panel (in the bottom left, or press F6). Could you aupdate the first image showing them?

Comment: If I understand you right, it's done.

Comment: The Spin tool is view dependant.. you can notice that the tutorial author enters top ortho view before spinning. Another way to adjust the axis around which the spin happens is in the operator options as @Carlo mentioned.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24496/how-can-i-create-a-profile-and-rotate-it-to-create-a-mesh-using-blender-2-72

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today with a fresh mind I got the point. The thing is that need stupidly select all points by pressing `a` and then use `Spin Tool` by `Alt+r`,  then all is fine. By the way, center of rotation determined by 3D cursor.

These thing's is simple, isn't it? But I faced with this problems, so I think that this information can be useful.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add an array-modifier and put the offset based on object, what should be an empty with set rotation and translation.

This is the hint: http://blender-tutorial.de/blender-tutorial-teil-21-der-array-modifier-5380/

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what is exactly meaning of 'spin the vertices', but you can just simply rotate the vertices to press R.

If you want to rotate the object,

1. Select Object mode on bottom of the screen. (You can do this to press Tab too.)
2. Press A to select your object
3. Press R and rotate as you want it.

I hope this would be helpful to you.

Comment: You'have got me wrong, i trying to make a glass with spin tool