# Screw modifier - how TO make a dome by choosing pivot vertex

Tags: modeling, screw-modifier

how to specify vertex to pivot around?

image 2 : Why can't I draw an edge/line between these two vertices?
[image][image]

Comment: Hi schmuck, There is a distinction between a mesh and a curve.  Related re spinning or screwing a profile https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35485/15543  Object above is a curve, can have a closed curve (eg a circle) but cannot fork a curve. (_ie_ at most a point is connected to two splines (spline being curve equivalent of mesh edge)) By trying to join the two curve control points in question, would need to fork at both ends.... hence the error.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24496/how-can-i-create-a-profile-and-rotate-it-to-create-a-mesh-using-blender-2-72

Comment: @batfinger  what do you mean. fork at both ends? 

Also why can I not spin the curve into a dome?

Comment: Two questions above, have a look at answer to link posted re what the profile should look like https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24498/15543  The other is re trying to join curve control points. A curve cannot go off in 3 or more directions from a control point. IMO opinion this  is  a different question, an perhaps should be asked instead as a [New Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)